# JSHint in old ES5 project

Tags: javascript, phpstorm, jshint

I use PhpStorm and JSHint.

We use the JavaScript std code style which removes semi colons, instead using the end of line indicator.

The production code is run through uglifyjs.

The problem is, the IDE wont stop warning about the missing semi-colon at the end of each line.

How can I configure JSHint in PhpStorm to ignore missing `;` at the end of lines?

Comment: You configure WebStorm inspection to not check this rule. Uncheck "Unterminated statement".

Comment: Ah ha! Thank you. For any googlers, i applied this setting and also had to restart the ide